# Render Canvas element in Onsen UI Application

Tags: cordova, fabricjs, onsen-ui

I'm trying to create a hybrid mobile app with onsen ui and fabric.js . i tasted and worked with both libraries separately and both of them suite my needs very well .

now the problem i'm facing is that it seem like the canvas is not being rendered at all ! i tested that the script file creating and maintaining the canvas is running and it does , but yet no rendering .

i will copy a part of the code here to illustrate the problem , i can post the hole app if necessarily .

**index.html**

```
<script src="lib/onsen/js/angular/angular.js"></script>    
  <script src="lib/onsen/js/onsenui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.transit.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fabric.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/spectrum.js"></script>
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/darwScript.js"></script>
  </head> 

// rest of the main html file ... 

<ons-template id="drawTemp.html">
    <ons-page>

        <ons-toolbar>
            <div class="left"><ons-back-button>بازگشت</ons-back-button></div>
        </ons-toolbar>

        <canvas id="c" width="400" height="400" style="border: 1px solid crimson"></canvas>

    </ons-page>
</ons-template>
```

**darwScript.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c") ;
    canvas.allowTouchScrolling = true ;
    canvas.setBackgroundColor("#000") ;
    canvas.renderAll() ;

    console.log("drawing page loaded") ;



      var text = new fabric.Text("Text" , {
            left : 150 , top : 150
        }) ;
        canvas.add(text) ;
}
```

i tested with a text element and setting the background color and none worked . but the canvas element
t is there and can be seen with an inline css borderColor i gave it .

thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that it won't be rendered until that page (under template drawTemp.html) is initialized...

You could add an ID for the page under that template:

```
<ons-template id="drawTemp.html">
    <ons-page id="canvasPage">
```

...and copy that logic (under document.ready) to this and see if it works?

```
$(document.body).on('pageinit', '#canvasPage', function() {
   var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c") ;
   canvas.allowTouchScrolling = true ;
   canvas.setBackgroundColor("#000") ;
   canvas.renderAll() ;

   console.log("drawing page loaded") ;



   var text = new fabric.Text("Text" , {
        left : 150 , top : 150
    }) ;
    canvas.add(text) ;
}
```

**EDIT**

Okay, so I went to canvasjs.com and grabbed an example and played with it. Here's what I got it to work:

I detected the "postpush" as the Navigator pushes the page onto the stack and call the canvas script.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
ons.bootstrap();

ons.ready(function() {
  myNavigator.on('postpush', function(event) {
      loadChart();
  });
});

function loadChart() {
          var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
              theme: "theme2",//theme1
              title:{
                  text: "Basic Column Chart - CanvasJS"              
             },
              data: [              
              {
// Change type to "bar", "splineArea", "area", "spline", "pie",etc.
                  type: "column",
                  dataPoints: [
                  { label: "apple", y: 10 },
                  { label: "orange", y: 15 },
                  { label: "banana", y: 25 },
                  { label: "mango", y: 30 },
                  { label: "grape", y: 28 }
                  ]
              }
              ]
          });

          chart.render();
      }
```

See it Live here: 'http://codepen.io/vnguyen972/pen/flwDi'

Comment: thanks a lot , but unfortunately it did not work . is there any example of a canvas with onesn on over the web ? i couldn't find any myself !

Comment: nope , just did . it tested it and worked fine , thanks :) another thing that i couldn't figure out why , but removing the angularJS template nad code ( re-writing the entire app.js with jQuery ) made your previous solution a good one as well .